# Leaflet - click on map object will trigger click on another map object

Tags: leaflet, buffer

i have this situation:

[image]

I want that clicking on the circle (buffer) around the marker will trigger a click on the marker.

This is where im creating the circle around the marker:

```
L.geoJSON(buffer).addTo(this.map).on("click", (e)=> marker.fire("click")
```

But unfortunately it doesnt work. The click on the circle is triggered but not triggering the click on the marker.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
This is the code:

```
this.drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map)
let currentLayer = this.drawnItems[index];

let bufMapObject = L.geoJSON(buffer).addTo(this.map).on("click", (e) => {
                console.log(currentLayer)
                currentLayer.fire("click")
            });
```

The output of `console.log(currentLayer)` is:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a complete example? `marker.fire("click")` should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697215/trigger-click-on-leaflet-marker/47697490#47697490

Comment: I've commented below with a bit more detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the relevant details? And describe what `currentLayer` is? It probably isn't your marker

Comment: Ok edited the question.