# Trigger marker mouse click event in R leaflet for shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

How can a marker click event be triggered in Leaflet for R?

The converse is [Marker mouse click event in R leaflet for shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938642/marker-mouse-click-event-in-r-leaflet-for-shiny) where the click event is captured.  I want to do the opposite and trigger the click event on a marker.  (The event will be fired by the user clicking on a row in a data table).

In javascript it looks like it can be done like this [Trigger click on leaflet marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697215/trigger-click-on-leaflet-marker)

Is this doable in Leaflet for R or do I have to use javascript?

Comment: Hello. What is the click supposed to do ?

Comment: For example, clicking on a marker will make a popup appear.  At the moment I'm using a tedious workaround where clicking on the data table creates a new popup at the same location - which is positioned to make it look as if the leaflet marker was clicked.

Comment: Did you manage to do it ? If so how ? I am really interested in how. I need it not only for a pop up since that is relatively easy, but for a rendering of a plot

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70298203/4322318) are a couple of options to answer the question.