# Programatically trigger marker mouse click event in R leaflet for shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, triggers, r-leaflet

My question is identical to this one: [Trigger marker mouse click event in R leaflet for shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962857/trigger-marker-mouse-click-event-in-r-leaflet-for-shiny) but I don't have enough rep to add a comment, and the edit queue is 'full' so I can't add my thoughts to the original question. Not sure if this goes against community rules/best practice, please remove if so! Apologies for the long winded description below but I think I might be close to a solution that a javascript or shiny guru could fix in no time! Or, I'm barking up the wrong tree completely. Thanks for reading!

##### I would like to trigger a Leaflet map marker click event when I select a row in a DT datatable in my R shiny web application.

Here's a min example app as a base for adding this functionality:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyjs)

# create js function that triggers a click on a button 'buttona'
jsCode <- 'shinyjs.buttonClick = (function() {
           $("#buttona").click();
           });'

df <- tibble::tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     label = c('One','Two','Three','Four','Five'),
                     lat = c(50,55,60,65,70), lng = c(0,5,-5,10,-10)
                     )

ui <- fluidPage(
    # new lines to enable shinyjs and import custom js function
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c('buttonClick')),

    leaflet::leafletOutput('map'),
    DT::DTOutput('table'),
    shiny::actionButton('buttona',"Button A") # new button
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
        leaflet::leaflet(options = leaflet::leafletOptions(minZoom = 3,maxZoom = 10)) %>%
            leaflet::setView(lng = 10,lat = 60,zoom = 3) %>%
            leaflet::addProviderTiles(provider = leaflet::providers$Esri.OceanBasemap) %>%
            leaflet::addMarkers(data = df,
                                layerId = ~id,
                                group = 'group1',
                                label = ~label,
                                lat = ~lat,
                                lng = ~lng,
                                popup = ~paste("<h3>More Information</h3>",
                                               "<b>Title:</b>",label,sep =" "))
    })
    output$table <- DT::renderDT(df,
                                 selection = 'single',
                                 rownames = FALSE,
                                 editable = FALSE
    )

    # observer looking for datatable row selection and triggering js function
    observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected,{
        shinyjs::js$buttonClick()
    })

    # observer looking for button click to trigger modal
    observeEvent(input$buttona,{
        showModal(
            modalDialog(title = "Test",
                        size = 'm',
                        h1("Test")
                        
            )
        )
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

##### Things I have tried:

##### shinyjs and javascript

I have been able to successfully use the shinyjs package to create similar funtionality with a button (see example app above), but when I try to do the same thing for the markers I just don't have the js knowledge to find the right element. By browsing in the js console in chrome I am able to find them manually, but they are within an iframe which I don't know how to programatically target, plus there is a random string in the location e.g. `jQuery351022343796258432992`.
Using manual location via chrome js console (I need to use the 'Elements' tab to select the #document within the iframe before this works) I can trigger the click event I want with the following lines:

```
var mymap = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet');
var els = mymap.map.jQuery351022343796258432992.leafletMap.layerManager._byGroup.group1;
els[0].fire('click'); //note this is the leaflet.js to trigger a marker click event
```

##### shinywidgets

There might be something in using `shinywidgets::onRender` as per the leaflet documentation at the bottom of this page https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html, but I don't know exactly how to implement it in this scenario.

Thanks again for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution using JS

After getting access to the Map object, you need to iterate over all the layers to find the marker with a specific id.

I modified the JS function you call with `shinyjs` to iterate over all the layers and fire the event `click` on the marker that matches the id. To avoid looking for the Map object every time, the Map object is retrieved after rendering using `htmlwidgets::onRender` function. As an alternative to `shinyjs`, you can use `runjs` to execute the function (not in code below).

```R
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyjs)

# create js function that triggers a click on a marker selected by a row in a DT
jsCode <- 'shinyjs.markerClick = function(id) {
              map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                if (layer.options.layerId == id) {
                  layer.fire("click");
                }
              })
           };'

df <- tibble::tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     label = c('One','Two','Three','Four','Five'),
                     lat = c(50,55,60,65,70), lng = c(0,5,-5,10,-10)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # new lines to enable shinyjs and import custom js function
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c('markerClick')),
  
  leaflet::leafletOutput('map'),
  DT::DTOutput('table'),
  shiny::actionButton('buttona',"Button A") # new button
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet::leaflet(options = leaflet::leafletOptions(minZoom = 3,maxZoom = 10)) %>%
      leaflet::setView(lng = 10,lat = 60,zoom = 3) %>%
      leaflet::addProviderTiles(provider = leaflet::providers$Esri.OceanBasemap) %>%
      leaflet::addMarkers(data = df,
                          layerId = ~id,
                          group = 'group1',
                          label = ~label,
                          lat = ~lat,
                          lng = ~lng,
                          popup = ~paste("<h3>More Information</h3>",
                                         "<b>Title:</b>",label,sep =" "))
    
    # assign the leaflet object to variable 'map'
    m <- m %>% 
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
          function(el, x) {
            map = this;
          }"
      )                                         
    
  })
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(df,
                               selection = 'single',
                               rownames = FALSE,
                               editable = FALSE
  )
  
  # observer looking for datatable row selection and triggering js function
  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected,{
    rowIndex <- input$table_rows_selected
    df$id[rowIndex]
    shinyjs::js$markerClick(df$id[rowIndex])
  })
  
  # observer looking for button click to trigger modal
  observeEvent(input$buttona,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(title = "Test",
                  size = 'm',
                  h1("Test")
                  
      )
    ) 
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Solution using Leaflet proxy

Just add a new popup every time a user selects a row in the table. It is important to use the same `layerId` to automatically update a popup that could be already on the map. Also, since the popup is going to be placed on the marker `lat` and `lng`, it is necessary to adjust the relative position on pixels using `offset`.

```R
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- tibble::tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     label = c('One','Two','Three','Four','Five'),
                     lat = c(50,55,60,65,70), lng = c(0,5,-5,10,-10)
)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  leaflet::leafletOutput('map'),
  DT::DTOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet::leaflet(options = leaflet::leafletOptions(minZoom = 3,maxZoom = 10)) %>%
      leaflet::setView(lng = 10,lat = 60,zoom = 3) %>%
      leaflet::addProviderTiles(provider = leaflet::providers$Esri.OceanBasemap) %>%
      leaflet::addMarkers(data = df,
                          layerId = ~id,
                          group = 'group1',
                          label = ~label,
                          lat = ~lat,
                          lng = ~lng,
                          popup = ~paste("<h3>More Information</h3>",
                                         "<b>Title:</b>",label,sep =" "))
    
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(df,
                               selection = 'single',
                               rownames = FALSE,
                               editable = FALSE
  )
  
  # observer looking for datatable row selection and use leaflet proxy to add a popup
  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected,{
    rowIndex <- input$table_rows_selected
    df$id[rowIndex]
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    addPopups(
      proxy,
      lng = df$lng[rowIndex],
      lat =df$lat[rowIndex],
      popup = paste("<h3>More Information</h3>",
                    "<b>Title:</b>",df$label[rowIndex],sep =" "),
      layerId = "popup",
      options  = popupOptions(offset = list (x = 0, y = -26))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with leaflet, but can't we more simply use the proxy?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just tried to answer the question as asked using the  "click event..." I added the solution using a proxy that is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Geovany that is the solution I needed. The JS version works better for me for two reasons: I only have to define the popup content once, which is more desirable in my use case, and the proxy version creates a situation where two popups can co-exist on the map. Other than that both solutions are great, so thanks also @Stéphane for the alternate suggestion. Just one note, with the JS solution the 'mousehover' labels stick over the markers. I'll figure that out, and it's not a big problem compared to the added functionality though!

Comment: I think the Proxy solution might be appropriate for this question Geovany https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962857/trigger-marker-mouse-click-event-in-r-leaflet-for-shiny if you want to paste it in there.

Comment: I’m glad it worked out. I added a link to the question you pointed me.